# Construct a divergence free symmetric $(2,0)$ tensor on curved manifold withsout Riemann tensor.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

On the flat manifold, one can construct a divergence-free symmetric $(2,0)$ tensor in this way.

- Step 1: Define an arbitrary tensor $K^{abcd}$ with Riemann tensor like symmetry
  $$K^{(ab)cd}=K^{ab(cd)}=0\, , K^{abcd}=K^{cdab}.$$
- Step 2: Define a $(2,0)$ tensor $H^{ab}$ such that
  $$H^{ab}=\nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}K^{acbd}\ .$$
  One easily check $H^{ab}=H^{ba}$ by
  $$H^{ab}=\nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}K^{acbd}=\nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}K^{bdac}=H^{ba}.$$
  And it is divergence-free
  \begin{align} 
  \nabla_a\nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}K^{acbd}&=-\nabla_a\nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}K^{acbd}+[\nabla_a,\nabla_c]\nabla_{d}K^{acbd}\\
  &=-\nabla_a\nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}K^{acbd}\\
  \nabla_aH^{ab}&=\nabla_a\nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}K^{acbd}\\
  &=0\,.
     \end{align}
  from the first line to the second line,  we have used the flat condition $[\nabla_a,\nabla_c]=0$.

**My question is**, is there a similar method to construct a divergence free symmetric $(2,0)$ tensor on a curved manifold with a zero Ricci but allowing a non-zero Riemann tensor? And this construction should satisfy that

- **dont include the Riemann tensor and any tensor in its family (Ricci, Weyl...)**
- **linear on an arbitrary tensor (any type) and its derivatives. Thus the freedom of adapting this tensor is only to set its anti/symmetry.**

The above construction on a flat manifold absolutely satisfies those conditions. But, with the appearance of a curved connection, both symmetric and divergence-free conditions are broken.

Comment: Note that $K = \operatorname{Rc} - \frac{1}{2}Sg$ works. Or down the error term (which appears when you commute two covariant derivatives and involves the curvature and the covariant derivative of $K$) and see if you can impose assumptions on the curvature tensor or $K$ or both so that the divergence vanishes.

Comment: I (I am not a student in math) am not familiar with your notation $K=Rc-Sg/2$. Please explain the meaning of it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I meant setting $H_{ab}$ equal to the Einstein tensor, i.e., $H_{ab} = R_{ab} - \frac{1}{2}Sg_{ab}$, where $R_{ab}$ is the Ricci curvature tensor and $S$ is the scalar curvature.

Comment: Thanks. But what I want to do is to find a divergence-free symmetric 2-tensor given by a linear combination of some free tensor or scalar (independent with metric) and its derivatives. And at most, the only assumption of metric is $R_{ab}=0$.  I have tried to write some construction and found only $\Theta^{ab}=(\nabla^a\nabla^b-g^{ab}\nabla^c\nabla_c)\phi$($\phi$ is an arbitrary scalar) fulfilled the above needs. However, the parameter space of this construction is too small. So I want to find a construction that leaves enough degrees of freedom to adjust something.

Comment: Without any assumptions on the metric and its curvature, this does not look easy to do. Most likely, you'll need some assumptions on the Riemann curvature tensor and the tensor $K$. In your calculation, the term that causes trouble i $[\nabla_a,\nabla_c]\nabla_dK^{acbd}$. On the other hand, this term can be written in terms of the Riemann curvature tensor and the covariant derivative of $K$. Assume it does not vanish. This means there will be an extra term in each line of calculation after that. You then assume that the last one vanishes.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful arguments! I think you are right, it is not easy to find such a construction without any assumption for metric-dependence of $K$.